# How to get all child visible on screen in HorizontalScrollView android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I add many `ImageView` to `HorizontalScrollView`, each `ImageView` load image from internet. But screen only display 3 `ImageView`.

I want to know what `ImageView` is on screen because I want to remove image from another `ImageView` that not display in screen.

Is there anyway to do that ?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: And if you are in a larger screen (like a tablet) it might display more than three, right?

Comment: yes. I caculate screen width and change number imageView display on each screen

Comment: So, what's your problem? You have the screen width and you know the number of the ImageView needed to be displayed.

Comment: I know the number of ImageView needed but don't know id of them. I want to load image in ImageView which dislay in screen. All other ImageView doesn't load until its display on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider using [`lazy ListView`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20lazy%20listview) instead of `<ScrollView>` for your images. With a lazy ListView, the app won't download the hidden images until the user scroll to view them.

I'm not familiar with such a ListView but I think those links might help you:

- [Question: How to do a lazy load of images in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541966/543711)

  - [A solution implemented](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)
- [Project: Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)